# ANDROID_SDK_HOME , a system variable or user variable?

Tags: java, android-studio

I tried setting **ANDROID_SDK_HOME** variable in following way  :-

**Control panel -> Advanced system setting -> Environment variables -> ....**

After that I got two options whether to create `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` variable as a **SYSTEM VARIABLE** or a **USER VARIABLE**. And what should the **VALUE** of  this variable be.

Pictorial answers will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether it should be a system or user variable depends on a few specific factors. A system variable applies to all user (and service) accounts on your computer, while a user variable applies to only your Windows user account. 
If your Windows user account is the only one used for Android development, then a user variable is appropriate.

The value of this variable should point to the location where you extracted the Android SDK on your computer. If you used the installer and not the ZIP file, the environment variable should already be set.

[image: Image showing the path in an example setup, and the folders that would be expected within the Android SDK]